# How to control two snakes in the snake game with the same keyboard at once (JAVA)

Tags: java, input, controls

I am currently trying to develop a snake game with two different snakes in the same game, in order to play with two people. I am using code that I found on the internet, and it worked. However when I decide to add a second snake, to be controlled with WASD and the first one to be controlled by the arrow keys only the first snake will move...

I have put a link below to the repl page with all my code

https://repl.it/@AmirGareev/Snake

Comment: Don't put links of your code, put your code in your question .

Comment: Sure this isn't a keyboard problem?

Comment: There is too much of the code to be able to paste it on here... It wouldn't allow me to post the question.

Comment: @paulJanssesns I've tested it and can move the snake with WASD but not both at the same time controlling the two seperate snakes

Comment: @studentofschoolwhoneedhelpfix Do not include all of your code in the question, only the relevant parts. This is called a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and is essential for good questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only methods `keyPressed`, `keyReleased` and `keyTyped` will receive key events. Methods `keyPressed1` and `keyReleased1` will not receive any events as they are not part of the `KeyListener` interface.

You must handle the keys for both snakes in `keyPressed`, `keyRelease` and `keyTyped` only.

Comment: The KeyListener methods can only receive a single KeyEvent parameter. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html for more details. I have updated the code for you here https://repl.it/repls/MurkySurprisedParser but I haven't tested it.